# Getting header value during Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, asp.net-web-api

While I am doing ajax call, I want access header value present in WEBAPI,How to call the header value.

Header is of this fromat in WEBAPI:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("SECURITY_TOKEN_KEY", TokenManager.CreateToken(objUserAuthentication.SUA_Login_Id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull it from the request headers as follows:

```
var headers = Request.Headers.GetValues("AjaxHeader");
var ajaxHeader = headers.FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope it helps.

**[Get header from web method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057016/get-header-from-web-method)**

**[How to retrieve Ajax header in this asp.NET web api method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984011/how-to-retrieve-ajax-header-in-this-asp-net-web-api-method)**

Answer (score 0):

Hi simply you can use getAllResponseHeaders method to get all header value.Then you can filter out the required one based on key name.

```
var geturl;
  geturl = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://....',
    success: function () {
      alert("done!"+ geturl.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
  });
```